# Cassandra Cache Size & JVM Heap Size

Tags: java, caching, nosql, cassandra

I am creating a very read-heavy set of node(s) for Cassandra. I am using Cassandra as a cache layer between a relational database and the data readers for certain types of data. Writes will only be in the form of synchronizing data from the relational database to Cassandra. I am trying to maximize the cache size of Cassandra for improved read performance.

What is the optimal cache size (I am using both partition key and row cache) in relation to the heap?

Technology

- JDK 1.7
- Cassandra 2.x
- 64 GB ram

Summary

- Optimal java heap size & Cassandra cache size?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra doesn't really have a specific "Optimal", its very dependent on application. I'm guessing a standard size heap for you though, as cache is offloaded into system ram. Load up your jconsole and try various configurations and see how it changes your cache hit rate.

Also when optimizing for reads, you're going to want to keep the data per node low, say under 500GB per node and use SSDs for your storage.

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/maximizing-cache-benefit-with-cassandra